# Import Java files from different directory

Tags: java, classpath

Could someone help me setup a `.classpath` for java?
I'm trying to import java files from the parent's child on my current file

```
src/
  dir1/
    main.java
  dir2/
    file1.java
    file2.java
    ...
```

How should I setup my classpath so I can do `import dir2.*` inside `main.java`?
I know that there is a command in linux to create the a classpath I just don't know how to do it, I've also searched for that information but couldn't understand either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class names per strong convention start with a capital. So:

```
src/
  dir1/
    Main.java
  dir2/
    File1.java
    File2.java
```

Main.java

```
package dir1;
import dir2.File1;
import dir2.File2;
public class Main { ... }
```

File1.java

```
package dir2;
import dir1.Main;
public class File1 { ... }
```

File2.java

```
package dir2;
import dir1.Main;
public class File2 { ... }
```

The `--classpath dir1:dir2` normally in a separate build directory for .class files, often named `target` or `build`.

You are saying that the sources are generated. I still would experiment with an IDE, like IntelliJ Community Edition. For checking, formating, own library code, directory conventions, maven or gradle build infrastructure.

For modular java, since java 9, one needs a `src/module-info.java` (small letters).

Comment: I can't add the package name to the files because im using ANTLR4 and when I do antlr4-build it will rewrite some of the needed files and remove the "package" line is there any other way to do it? Creating a `.classpath` for example?

Comment: You may compile inside dir1 and dir2 (default empty package). When using a separate destination directory for the .class files, you can use that directory as classpath.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the import keyword in your main class, the following snippet demonstrates that

```
import dir2.*;
public class mainClass {
    //other implementations
}
```

Comment: that will not work because dir2 isn't a subdirectory of dir1, for me to use that I need to setup my classpath as the parent directory

Comment: are there any classes or interfaces in the dir2 directory gonna inherited by the dir1 directory? if yes, your IDE will automatically help you achieve that

Comment: I cannot use an IDE because I'm dealing with a language builder called ANTLR4, and the interfaces or classes are not inherited